# Google Application Engine DTO to JDO

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, dto

Is there anyway to transfer JDOs accross RPC as DTO such in GWT, we used to have Gilead for hibernate Objects??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And Gilead has code for use of DataNucleus with GAE/J; look at their SVN for details